# Understanding hash creation

Tags: ruby

I am very new to Ruby and I'm trying to understand the following hash creation:

```
hash = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }
```

How can I interpret it? The syntax (the content of the block) is not clear to me yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Hash.new` - You're calling the Hash's constructor

`{ |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }` - you're passing this block to the constructor.  This block says to the Hash: when you encounter an unknown key, create a new key/value pair, with that key as the key, and a newly allocated empty array as the value.

`hash =` - You're assigning the new hash to this variable.  But don't use `hash` as a variable name!  It's already the name of a method on every object whose class subclasses `Object`.

There is also a simpler notation:

```
Hash.new([])
```

but that is rarely what you want, because a) all references to nonexistent keys will share the same array, and b) it does not result in the creation of any key/value pairs:

```
2.3.0 :001 > h = Hash.new([])
 => {}
2.3.0 :002 > h[:a] << 1
 => [1]
2.3.0 :003 > h[:b]
 => [1]
2.3.0 :004 > h.keys.include? :a
 => false
2.3.0 :005 > h.keys
 => []
```

Regarding the syntax of `|hash, key|`, that fragment serves exactly the same purpose as the parenthesized argument list of a method, e.g. `(hash, key)` in the code below:

```
def f(hash, key)
  hash[key] = []
end
```

Comment: `Hash.new([])` doesn't assign any value to any key (when a missing key is called). It just keeps returning the same **default** array. `h = Hash.new([]); h[:a]; h # => {}`.

Comment: @sawa Thank you for that clarification.  I've modified my answer to incorporate it.